# Custom questionnaire with drag and drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I build a custom questionnaire.
On the left side, I have TOOLS (input, select, etc) and on the right side is DROP zone...

I need to create a questionnaire form with this form tools and save this to API (for the test to session storage)...
When I drag&drop, let's say INPUT, in drop zone I get source code...
[You can see this in the example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9kjw6-vkqbnf?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html)

So my question is, which is the best way to do this?

What I try:

- Create a reusable component (input-component, text-component, select-component...) and give a unique ID
  to every component, and in DRAG zone with *ngFor loop thru all component. But, I get only source code like in the example
- Also, to store these selected components and/or show them to edit again when I get them from API. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create form component, which will contain all your edit/create logic. `@Input` is your questionnaire object(edit) or null(create). Drag and drop logic should be outside (in your list component there). Also think about relations between them, create service that will notify list component when item is edited/created.

Comment: good point... do you have some example? something similar, because I try to find something similar, but nothing fits to my needed

Comment: is there problem with drag and drop implementation or reusable components?

Comment: I know how to do this with reusable components.... problem is for drag and drop

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts there is a drag&drop feature in `mat-tree` you could play around this

Comment: thnx, but i can't find in this example why in `DROP` zone show me source code